# Can you run Google Colab on your local computer?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

My PC is rocking a 2080TI so I don't really need the GPU computation of Google Colab, but I do find it a nice development environment (in comparison to jupyter notebooks) and I like the fact that I can access my files from anywhere, so, is it possible to use Google Colab but let my local pc do the computation?

Comment: Yes, there is an option to use Local GPU if you want. There is an option called _Connect_ where you can select "Connect to local runtime"

Comment: @segfault404 can you please elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: Open Google Collab, click at the dropdown near "Connect" option and select "Connect to local runtime" . Run jupyter-notebook on your PC and enter the required URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steps:

- Go to `Google colab` and click on connect to local runtime, a pop-up comes.
  [image]
- Go to your terminal and execute:

```
jupyter notebook   --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'   --port=8888   --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

If this shows error:

```
ERROR: the notebook server could not be started because port 8888 is not available.
```

Then run the following to basically kill any process using it or use another port:

1. `lsof -wni tcp:8888`
2. `kill -9 <JOB_ID>`

If successful, then the command gives a link:

For example:

```
http://localhost:8888/?token=bb80b05aef71999353fe4715e0f06be40d22911648dbdcd6
```

Copy it in the pop-up in the colab and you are set to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you: [research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html)