# How do I change my working directory in a proper manner?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, working-directory, chdir, getcwd

**I'm working in Google Colab and I'm trying to change to working directory to my desktop (desktop = bureaublad in dutch thats why you see 'bureaublad in my path). However, changing the working directory keeps giving me the error that such a directory doesn't exist. I just copied the path so everything should exist! See my code here:**

Code:

```py
import os
print(os.getcwd())
os.listdir()
```

Output:

```sh
/content
['.config', 'sample_data']
```

Code:

```py
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\emile\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Completed Communications Transcriptions')
```

Output:

```sh
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-c4d97f3ec347> in <module>()
----> 1 os.chdir(r'C:\Users\emile\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Completed Communications Transcriptions')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\emile\\OneDrive\\Bureaublad\\Completed Communications Transcriptions'
```

**What did I do wrong?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You need to be connected to a local runtime by hosting a jupyter notebook server and then enter port number then you can succesfully connect if you are connected to a hosted runtime you can only connect to google drive by mounting it.**

More information can be found here- [Can you run Google Colab on your local computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087188/can-you-run-google-colab-on-your-local-computer)

Comment: It finally worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `/` instead of `\`

```
import os
os.chdir('C:/')
```

Also check that the path is correct because in your example I see `chdir(r'C:/')` instead of `chdir('C:/')`